# Regex - counting the number of colons in a string

Tags: regex, count, expression

New here so apologise if i miss out any critical information!

I've been using https://regex101.com/ to try and build some regex for the following -

I want to use some regex code to either return true if the number of colons in a text string is 3 and false if it is 4 or more, for example the following text string should return false -

Bin Not Out at:12:54:38Wrong Colour Bin at:12:43:17

but this should return a match -

Bin Not Out at:12:54:38

Alternatively I had been looking at other methods to get a relevant response such as \d\d\D\d\d\D\d\d\D i.e. if there is a letter straight after a digit return a true value but i'm really struggling trying to get it to work.

Any help on either option would be appreciated as either would flag what I need.

Many thanks!

Comment: Just count the colons. Using python as an example `len("yourstring".split(":"))`

Comment: What happens if you have one or two colons in the string?

Comment: @FredrikPihl you will need a -1 on that. If you split on a string with 1 `: ` the length is 2.

Comment: @MarkBaijens - True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match the format in your example data containing 3 times a colon, you might use:

```
^[^\r\n:]*:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[^\r\n:]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/55bAn4/1)

**That would match**

- `^` Assert start of the string
- `[^\r\n:]*` Negated character class to match not 0+ times a carriage return, newline or a colon
- `(?::\d{2}){3}` Match a colon followed by 2 digits and repeat that 3 times
- `[^\r\n:]*` Negated character class to match not 0+ times a carriage return, newline or a colon
- `$` Assert the end of the line

If the values to want to match are in 24h format, you might use this regex

```
^[^\r\n:]*:(?:2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):(?:[0-5]?[0-9]):(?:[0-5]?[0-9])[^\r\n:]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/55bAn4/2)

Comment: That is great, just what I was after, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex that matches strings containing 3 and only 3 colon:

```
^([^:]*:){3}[^:]*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/v1J5QM/1)

Answer (score -1):

Using Perl one liner

```
> cat colon.dat
Bin Not Out at:12:54:38Wrong Colour Bin at:12:43:17
Bin Not Out at:12:54:38
> perl -ne ' { while(m/(:)/g){$x++} print $x==3 ? "true\n":"false\n"  ; $x=0 } ' colon.dat
false
true
>
```

or more elegantly

```
> perl -ne ' { $x++ while(m/(:)/g) ; print $x==3 ? "true\n":"false\n"  ; $x=0 } ' colon.dat
false
true
>
```